# Using a property value from a document to access a property of another document inside a find query with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections, *letters* and *settings*, as defined below:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const letterSchema = new Schema({
  language: { type: String, required: true },
  content: { type: String, required: true },
  annotations: { type: Number, required: true }
});

const settingsSchema = new Schema({
  maxAnnotations: {
    toAllLanguages: {
      enabled: { type: Boolean, required: true },
      amount: { type: Number, required: true }
    }
    english: { type: Number, required: true },
    french: { type: Number, required: true },
    spanish: { type: Number, required: true },
    german: { type: Number, required: true },
    italian: { type: Number, required: true }
  },
  allowNewAnnotations: { type: Boolean, required: true }
}, capped: { max: 1 } });

module.exports = mongoose.model("Letter", letterSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model("Setting", settingsSchema);
```

I'm writing a REST api that will be consumed by a react frontend. Each schema is written in a separate file, but I wrote them together here to simplify things. I'm trying to write a query where I can get all letters whose number of annotations did not exceeded the maximum amount defined in the settings according to the language of the letter. And only certain languages are allowed to have annotations. Let's suppose only letters in english and french are allowed to have annotations, like this:

```
const allowedLanguages = ["english", "french"];
```

So, based on these constraints, I came up with this code:

```
const Letters = require("../models/lettters");
const Settings = require("../models/settings");

exports.getLetters = async (req, res, next) => {
  const pageSize = +query.pagesize;
  const currentPage = +query.currentPage;

  const settings = await Settings.findOne();
  const toAllLanguages = settings.maxAnnotations.toAllLanguages.enabled;
  
  if (toAllLanguages ) {
    const letters = await Letters.find({
      language: { $in: allowedLanguages },
      annotations: { $lt: settings.maxAnnotations.toAllLanguages.amount }
    })
    .skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1))
    .limit(pageSize);
  } else {
    const letters = await Letters.find({
      language: { $in: allowedLanguages },
      $expr: {
        $lt: ["$annotations", settings.maxAnnotations["$language"]]
      }
    })
    .skip(pageSize * (currentPage - 1))
    .limit(pageSize);
  }
}
```

This code doesn't work when `toAllLanguages` is set to `false` because there is no property `"$language"` in the settings collection. I wonder if it is possible to get the value of language property in the letters document, and use this value to access a property in the settings document with the same name in the same find query.

To give a clearer idea of what I want to achieve, consider this json object to be the current configuration selected:

```
{
  "maxAnnotations": {
    "toAllLanguages": {
      "enabled": false,
      "amount": 3
    },
    "english": 2,
    "french": 4,
    "spanish": 5,
    "german": 2,
    "italian": 3
  },
  "allowNewAnnotations": true
}
```

Following this configuration, since `maxAnnotations.toAllLanguages.enabled` is set to false, I have to compare the language of the letter and the matching property of the configuration json object. In this example, the the find query should retrieve letters obeying these rules:

- letters in english and german must have less than 2 annotations;
- letters in french must have less than 4 annotations;
- letters in spanish must have less than 5 annotations;
- letters in italian must have less than 3 annotations

Comment: Hmm... Not sure I completely understood the question. If we assume FE sends "language" in request and in BE it's accessible with `req.language`, then why not use `$lt: ["$annotations", settings.maxAnnotations[req.language]]`?

Comment: It could work if I knew precisely which language is wanted. Besides, almost all the time, more than one language will be allowed, hence `allowedLanguages` is an array. The real problem is how can I access the settings object using the language property value of the letter

Comment: Can you provide an (roughly and not necessarily working) example of attempt and goal?

Comment: I also tried this: 
`$lt: ["$annotations", settings.maxAnnotations[language]]`
I want to reach the value of that language property of the letter and use this value to reach the property of the settings that has the same name.

Comment: It would still be better if you provide an example + expectation :)

Comment: I just updated the question with more info